# assign and iterate over many conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with a date column and I also have two lists with dates. One of the lists contains start dates and the other end dates (they have the same length). I would like to assign a new column called `variable` which is 1 if the date is between one of the start/end date pairs and 0 otherwise. I tried to do the below but it does not work. Is there a way to do this without loops?

```
start_dates = [date(2023,4,1), date(2023,4,24), date(2023,5,15)]
end_dates = [date(2023,4,14), date(2023,5,1), date(2023,5,30)]

no_days = 92
intervals = [date(2023, 3, 1) + timedelta(days=1*i) for i in range(0, no_days-2)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':intervals})

#does not work
df.assign(variable=np.where((df.date >= start) & (df.date <= end), 
1, 0) for start in start_dates for end in end_dates)
```

Comment: "I would like to assign a new column called variable which is 1 if the date is between one of the start/end date pairs" - and you consider **all possible pairs** of starts and ends? Or do you want to **match up corresponding** start and end dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us use broadcasting to compare the start and end date values against the date column

```
m1 = np.less_equal.outer(df['date'].values, end_dates)
m2 = np.greater_equal.outer(df['date'].values, start_dates)

df['var'] = np.any(m1 & m2, axis=1).astype('int')
```

---

```
          date  var
0   2023-03-01    0
1   2023-03-02    0
...
9   2023-03-10    0
10  2023-03-11    0
11  2023-03-12    0
12  2023-03-13    0
13  2023-03-14    0
14  2023-03-15    0
...
22  2023-03-23    0
23  2023-03-24    0
24  2023-03-25    0
25  2023-03-26    0
26  2023-03-27    0
27  2023-03-28    0
28  2023-03-29    0
29  2023-03-30    0
30  2023-03-31    0
31  2023-04-01    1
32  2023-04-02    1
...
86  2023-05-26    1
87  2023-05-27    1
88  2023-05-28    1
89  2023-05-29    1
```